# Should I build an expression or have many paths for the code?

Tags: c#

I have a C# 4.0 .Net app which currently parses lines of text looking for specific strings and I want to add the ability to have checkbox choice for search all directories, and also filter by extensions or all files.

I ended up doing several if/else statements with Directory.EnumerateFiles statement on each of four possible choices.

When I tried to assign the Enumerable to foreach to loop through all of them I kept getting stuck with errors on being out of context from the code above.
I am guessing I would need to have all of the code contained within each of the EnumerateFiles if/else block, or do I?

I am a VBA developer working hard to make the jump to C# and I find the scope and context to be the biggest challenges for me now. In VB I would have built a string of options and then concatenated them (&) to get an executable line of code but trying that with (+) and string variables has not had any success.

The if/else block I am talking about is below.

```
    try
        {
            string sourceDirectory =txtFolder.Text;
            var filters = new[] { txtFileExt.ToString() };
            var result = new List<string>();


            if (txtExtensionsFile == null)
            {
                if (chkSubFolderFiles.Checked)
                {
                    var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) ;
                }
                else
                {
                     var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) ;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (chkSubFolderFiles.Checked)
                {
                    var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => filters.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s)))) ;
                }
                else
                {
                    var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(s => filters.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s)))) ;
                }
            }
            foreach (string filename in txtFiles)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
                if (Path.GetExtension(filename) == txtFileExt.Text) 
    //continues on to parse out text from each file
    }
```

Comment: there are a couple of different ways to do this without using so much redundant code.. for example you could replace this with variables 
`var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\path\folder\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp3") || s.EndsWith(".jpg"));` you can mix and match.. and get all files this way too 
`var allFilenames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));`

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your if statement for example like this

```
var searchOption = chkSubFolderFiles.Checked ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.*", searchOption);
if (null != txtExtensionsFile)
    txtFiles = txtFiles.Where(s => filters.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s)));
```